# How to - Spring IoC and HttpClient 4.3.1 CloseableHttpClient?

Tags: java, spring, apache-httpclient-4.x

I'd like to have Spring IoC configure a `CloseableHttpClient` object and inject it into my class so that customization of its configuration can be done via XML.

From what I can see, `HttpClient` seems to resist this pattern quite forcibly. They want you to do things like

```
CloseableHttpClient chc =
    HttpClients.custom().set<thing that should be a property>().build();
```

Ick.

Is there not some mechanism for making a singleton `CloseableHttpClient` bean that I can then use?

Comment: With Java config, this is a breeze. Just declare a `@Bean` method that builds it.

Answer (score 44, accepted):

This seems to work for me:

```
<bean id="requestConfigBuilder" class="org.apache.http.client.config.RequestConfig"
    factory-method="custom">
    <property name="socketTimeout" value="${socketTimeoutInMillis}" /> 
    <property name="connectTimeout" value="${connectionTimeoutInMillis}" /> 
</bean>

<bean id="requestConfig" factory-bean="requestConfigBuilder" factory-method="build" />

<bean id="httpClientBuilder" class="org.apache.http.impl.client.HttpClientBuilder"
    factory-method="create">
    <property name="defaultRequestConfig" ref="requestConfig" />
</bean>

<bean id="httpClient" factory-bean="httpClientBuilder" factory-method="build" />
```

That gives me a CloseableHttpClient in the "httpClient" bean, with the socket and connection timeouts configured. You should be able to add more properties to either the requestConfigBuilder or the  httpClientBuilder.

Comment: Using Java configuration, this could be done within one bean only, by dividing the requestConfig bean and the httpClient, or copying the exact xml structure. Is there a best practice about what should be done? Does it even make sense in Java to divide the setup in four steps as in the XML configuration?

Comment: @user666 yes, this worked at the time (in 2014 on HttpClient 4.3.1).

Answer (score 9):

With Java config, this is as simple as

```
@Bean
public CloseableHttpClient httpClient() {
    HttpClientBuilder builder = HttpClientBuilder.create();
    builder.setEverything(everything); // configure it
    CloseableHttpClient httpClient = builder.build();
}
```

With XML config, it's a little more complex. You can create your own `FactoryBean` implementation, say `CloseableHttpClientFactoryBean`, which delegates all the calls to a `HttpClientBuilder` and calls `build()` inside `getObject()`.

```
public class CloseableHttpClientFactoryBean implements FactoryBean<CloseableHttpClient> {
    private HttpClientBuilder builder;
    public CloseableHttpClientFactoryBean() {
        builder = HttpClientBuilder.create();
    }

    ... // all the setters
    // for example
    public void setEverything(Everything everything) {
        // delegate
        builder.setEverything(everything);
    }

    public CloseableHttpClient getObject() {
        return builder.build();
    }
}
```

And the config

```
<bean name="httpClient" class="com.spring.http.clients.CloseableHttpClientFactoryBean">
    <property name="everything" ref="everything"/>
</bean>
```

You will need a setter method for each `HttpClientBuilder` method.

Note that if you don't need any custom configuration, you can use `factory-method` to get a default `CloseableHttpClient`

```
<bean name="httpClient" class="org.apache.http.impl.client.HttpClients" factory-method="createDefault" >
</bean>
```