# AutoWired getProperty returning null

Tags: spring

I have 2 classes in which i am getting the getProperty of autowired class as null

I will post my classes and explain the problem below
I have used autowiring but i am getting my output as null

**Connection.java**

```
@Component
public class Connection {

    private static org.apache.log4j.Logger logger = org.apache.log4j.Logger.getLogger(Connection.class);
    Logger basiclogger = Logger.getLogger("Main");


    public CloseableHttpClient httpClient;

        public static String Server;
        public static String service;
        public static String User;
        public static String Password;


        @Autowired
        public Connection(@Value("${Server}") String Server, @Value("${service}") String service,
               @Value("${User}") String User,@Value("${Password}") String Password)
            {
            Connection.Server = Server;
            Connection.service = service;
            Connection.User = User;
            Connection.Password = Password;

        }

        public Connection(){


        }


    public CloseableHttpClient getHttpClient() {

            return httpClient;
        }



        public void setHttpClient(CloseableHttpClient httpClient) {
            this.httpClient = httpClient;
        }



        public CloseableHttpClient makeConnection() {



                AuthenticatedClientBuilder builder = AuthenticatedClientBuilder.create(serviceProvider)
                .addServer(Server).setUser(User)
                .setPassword(Password);         
                httpClient = builder.build();
                basiclogger.info("Connection is Established SuccessFully");

                 return httpClient;
            } 

    }

}
```

**In Spring XML**

```
<bean id="conn" class="com.java.Connection"
         scope="prototype"/>
```

**In Main**

```
 @Autowired(required = true)
     Connection connection;

        new ClassPathXmlApplicationContext(new String[] {"Spring-batch-context.xml"});

                Connection connection = (Connection)context.getBean("conn");
                connection.getHttpClient();
                System.out.println("***********"+connection.getHttpClient()+"***********");
```

But i am getting connection.getHttpClient() as null

Can someone please help me

Thanks in advnace!!!!!!!!

Comment: Where this call is defined in xml "CloseableHttpClient ", it is not initialized or autowired using the xml so you are getting null.  Pass the  "CloseableHttpClient " object property to the Connection bean in xml. Refer [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20340470/how-to-spring-ioc-and-httpclient-4-3-1-closeablehttpclient)

Comment: <bean id="conn" class="com.java.Connection" scope="prototype">                           <property name="CloseableHttpClient"/>                                                                  </bean>                                                                                                                       Like this??

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to - Spring IoC and HttpClient 4.3.1 CloseableHttpClient?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20340470/how-to-spring-ioc-and-httpclient-4-3-1-closeablehttpclient)

Comment: i am getting default httpclient but iwant it using makeconnection() in Connection.java

Answer (score 0):

From :

```
Connection connection = (Connection)context.getBean("conn");
```

Remove `@Autowired` on Connection in main method and change to:

```
@Autowired
BeanFactory beanFactory;

Connection connection = beanFactory.getBean(Connection.class, "args");
```

`@Scope(value = "prototype")` means that Spring will not instantiate the bean right on start, but will do it later on demand.

**Update:**

Here is the Javadoc of `beanFactory.getBean()`

> `getBean(java.lang.Class<T> requiredType, java.lang.Object... args)`
>          throws BeansException
>   Return an instance, which may be shared or independent, of the specified bean.
>
> Allows for specifying explicit constructor arguments / factory method
>   arguments, overriding the specified default arguments (if any) in the
>   bean definition.
>
> This method goes into ListableBeanFactory by-type lookup territory but
>   may also be translated into a conventional by-name lookup based on the
>   name of the given type. For more extensive retrieval operations across
>   sets of beans, use ListableBeanFactory and/or BeanFactoryUtils.
>
> **Parameters**:
>
> **requiredType** - *type the bean must match; can be an interface or superclass*
>
> **args** - *arguments to use when creating a bean instance using explicit arguments*

---

> **Returns**: an instance of the bean
>
> **Throws**:
>
> *NoSuchBeanDefinitionException* - if there is no such bean definition
>
> *BeanDefinitionStoreException* - if arguments have been given but the affected bean isn't a prototype
>
> *BeansException* - if the bean could not be created

---

Further, read here: [BeanFactory](https://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/beans/factory/BeanFactory.html)

Comment: Still getting null

Comment: what spring version you are on?

Comment: 4.2.4 Spring version

Comment: Sorry, I missed this, you have used @Scope(value = "prototype") which means that Spring will not instantiate the bean right on start, but will do it later on demand.

Comment: should i use @Scope or should i not?

Comment: That depends on your requirement **scope:prototype** means a single bean definition to have any number of object instances. As you are passing values from the property file and it seems they will not change in the program lifecycle hence you may remove it or use **scope:singleton** which means bean definition to a single instance per Spring IoC container (default).

Comment: did you change the scope?

Comment: What is sourcesystem in ur answer @vancleff